# no hex response from server in python

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import struct
import time
import binascii

host = '127.0.0.1'          # Get local machine name
port = 5000                # Reserve a port for your service.
print 'Connecting to ', host, port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
message = 'EA68DF0102A100DF0360433a5c554c205465737420546f6f6c735c42545420352e322e315c4170706c69636174696f6e5c5375697465735c496d616765735c566973615c436f6e746163745c414456542076362e312e315c54657374436172643031202d20412e786d6c'
s.sendall(message)
data = binascii.hexlify(message).decode()
print "sent message:", data
data = s.recv(4096) 
data = binascii.hexlify(data).decode()
print "received message:", data
s.close()
```

---

'received message' should be in hex form but its blank as:

```
received message:
```

Comment: What is the value of `data`received just before you decode it?

Comment: I just forgot to remove this function occurring twice:

Comment: please remove this .....data = binascii.hexlify(message).decode()

Comment: Still the error persists?

Comment: I want output something like   .... EB 09 DF 01 02 A1 and so on

Comment: Are you still getting the error?

Comment: yes. received message is :

Comment: no response from server

Comment: Can you post the relevant server code snippet?

Comment: actually I don't have server code.. as I m getting response from automation tool. I m writing test driver to run the tool

Comment: its card server which is showing connected but not responding to my TLV